# How to delete a object in a list? Javascript nodejs and underscore

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

Hello I am new to Javascript and NodeJS, but I need to delete a object in a array with a boolean in the list. There are 3 friends in the list and 2 friends with `isEvil = true;` So i need to delete 2 friends and the output must be 1.
This is what i tried.

MyTry 1:

```
_.each(user.friends, function(friend) {
    if(friend.isEvil){
        delete friend;
    }
});
console.log(user.friends.length); //output is 3
```

If I do this it will delete all the properties but there is still a empty object  there: MyTry 2:

```
_.each(user.friends, function(friend) {
    if(friend.isEvil){
        delete f.property1;
        delete f.property2;
    }
});
console.log(user.friends.length); //output is 3
```

And the last one i tried is:

```
_.each(user.friends, function(friend, key) {
    if(friend.isEvil){
        delete user.friends[key];
    }
});
console.log(user.friends.length); //output is 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just use the `_.filter(list, predicate, [context])` function provided with `underscore`:

```
_.filter(user.friends, function(friend){ 
                             return !friend.isEvil; 
  });
```

for more info: http://underscorejs.org/#filter

Comment: They need not evil friends, so correct you condition to 

return !friend.isEvil

Answer (score 2):

Filter the users friend like

```
user.friends.filter(function (friend) {
    return !friend.isEvil;
});
```

```js
var frieds = [{ name: 1, isEvil: false }, { name: 2, isEvil: true }, { name: 3, isEvil: true }];

var notEvil = friends.filter(function (friend) {
    return !friend.isEvil;
});

console.log(notEvil);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of evil friends you could use underscore's [**reject**](http://underscorejs.org/#reject) function:

```
var niceFriends = _.reject(friends, 'isEvil');
```

```js
var friends = [
 { id: 'mickey', isEvil: false }, 
 { id: 'donald', isEvil: true }, 
 { id: 'minnie', isEvil: false }
 ];

var niceFriends = _.reject(friends, 'isEvil');

document.getElementById('result').textContent = JSON.stringify(niceFriends);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.2/underscore.js"></script>

<p>
  <pre id="result"></pre>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,basically you iterate though you array and splice all unwanted objects:

```
for(var i in user.friends){
    if(user.friends[i].isEvil){

         user.splice(i,1)
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete operator leaves your array with undefined on the place of removed element (see [delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b2z052x(v=vs.94).aspx)). I believe you should use [Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method to remove elements.
Or you might just use built in Underscores methods to filter your array (e.g. [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter)), like:

```
user.friends = _.filter(user.friends, function(item) {
    return !item.isEvil;
};
```